# Calling inline function in .cu file from C++ class

Tags: c++, class, cuda, gpgpu

I'm trying to call a kernel wrapper `foo` from a C++ class. I've tried to do as suggested [here](http://blog.mpanknin.de/?p=538) below:

```
// In CPP.h:
class cls {
    extern "C" inline void foo();
}

// In Kernels.cu:
#include "CPP.h"
extern "C" inline void cls::foo() {
    // call kernels here
}
```

but this has not worked - I get a compiler errors:

- `CPP.h: invalid storage class for a class member`
- `CPP.h: "cls::foo" was referenced but not defined`
- `Kernels.cu: label "cls" was declared but never referenced`

What's going wrong?

Comment: It is pretty simple, code inside classes must have C++ linkage.

Comment: @talonmies - so member `cls::foo` should be defined only in the C++ file, and it should call a C++ non-member marked with `extern C`, which in turn calls the CUDA kernel wrapper in the `.cu` file, which in turn calls the kernels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mark a class method with `extern "C"`.

Make a wrapper non-member function with `extern "C"` specifier, and let this function call your class's method (you will need to specify an instance also).

Comment: Make wrapper to call class method? Sure it should be the other way round - I want my C++ class method to call a CUDA-C kernel wrapper, so that cls::foo() will cause execution on the GPU. Thanks.

Comment: Then it should be even easier: implement your wrapper function as a non-member with `extern "C"` and call it from any class method just like any other function (you do not have to make this function a class member).